# How connnect Samsung TV to hard disk with samba connected to router

Tags: samba, smb, samsung

Hi guys i have connected to router a ssd disk. So i can connect to them since android phone
and windows pc but how can i connect from tv samsung  (UE65TU7125KXXC).
In my pc i can connect with the next adress \routerip\samba\ssdname but In the TV I can't access.

Do you know any app or method for solved this?.